# No data received when using RTCDataChannel.send()

Tags: javascript, node.js, webrtc

I am trying to develop a simple chat using WebRTC. The WebRTC connection is established but I am not able to send data to the other peer.

This is my signaling server (I think that this should not be the problem):

```js
import { WebSocketServer } from 'ws';
import express from 'express';
import path from 'path';

const PORT = 3000;

const app = express();
app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile("index.html");
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});

function sendTo(connection, message) { 
  connection.send(JSON.stringify(message)); 
}

let wss = new WebSocketServer({ port: 9090 });

// All users connected to the server
let users = {};

//when a user connects to our sever 
wss.on('connection', (connection) => {
  console.log("user connected");

  //when server gets a message from a connected user 
  connection.on('message', (message) => {
    let data;

    //accepting only JSON messages 
    try {
      data = JSON.parse(message);
    } catch (e) {
      console.error("Invalid JSON");
      data = {};
    }

    //switching type of the user message 
    switch (data.type) {
      //when a user tries to login 
      case "login":
        console.log("User logged:", data.name);

        //if anyone is logged in with this username then refuse 
        if (users[data.name]) {sendTo(connection, {type: "login", success: false});
        } else {
          //save user connection on the server 
          users[data.name] = connection;
          connection.name = data.name;
          sendTo(connection, {type: "login", success: true});
        }
        break;
      case "offer":
        //for ex. UserA wants to call UserB 
        console.log(`Sending offer: from ${connection.name} to ${data.name}`);
        //if UserB exists then send him offer details 
        let userOfferConn = users[data.name];
        if(userOfferConn != null){ 
          //setting that UserA connected with UserB 
          connection.otherName = data.name; 
          sendTo(userOfferConn, {type: "offer", offer: data.offer, name: connection.name}); 
        }
        break;
      case "answer":
        console.log(`Sending answer: from ${connection.name} to ${data.name}`);
        //for ex. UserB answers UserA 
        let userAnswerConn = users[data.name];
        if(userAnswerConn != null) { 
          connection.otherName = data.name; 
          sendTo(userAnswerConn, {type: "answer", answer: data.answer}); 
        }
        break;
      case "candidate":
        console.log(`Sending candidate from ${connection.name} to ${data.name}`);
        let userCandidateConn = users[data.name];
        if(userCandidateConn != null) {
          sendTo(userCandidateConn, {type: "candidate", candidate: data.candidate}); 
        }
        break;
      case "leave":
        console.log(`Disconnecting: ${connection.name} & ${data.name}`);
        let userDiscConn = users[data.name];
        userDiscConn.otherName = null;
        if(conn != null) {
          // Notify the other user so he can disconnect his peer connection
          sendTo(userDiscConn, {type: "leave"}); 
        } 
      default:
        sendTo(connection, {type: "error", message: "Command no found: " + data.type});
        break;
    }

    connection.on("close", () => { 
      if(connection.name) { 
        delete users[connection.name];

        if(connection.otherName) {
          console.log(`Disconnecting: ${connection.name} & ${connection.otherName}`);
          let userDiscConn = users[connection.otherName];
          userDiscConn.otherName = null;
          if(userDiscConn != null) {
            sendTo(userDiscConn, {type: "leave"});
          }
        }
      }
    });
  });
});
```

This is my client html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <input type="text" id="loginInput" />
        <button id="loginBtn">Login</button>
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="text" id="otherUsernameInput" />
        <button id="connectToOtherUsernameBtn">Establish connection</button>
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="text" id="msgInput" />
        <button id="sendMsgBtn">Send text message</button>
    </div>

    <script src="client.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

And this is the client Javascript:

```js
let connection = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:9090');
 let username = "";

 let loginInput = document.getElementById("loginInput");
 let loginBtn = document.getElementById("loginBtn");

 let otherUsernameInput = document.getElementById("otherUsernameInput");
 let connectToOtherUsernameBtn = document.getElementById("connectToOtherUsernameBtn");

 let msgInput = document.getElementById("msgInput");
 let sendMsgBtn = document.getElementById("sendMsgBtn");

 let connectedUser, myConnection, dataChannel;

 function send(message) {
   if (connectedUser) {
     message.name = connectedUser;
   }
   connection.send(JSON.stringify(message));
 }

 // When a user clicks the login button 
 loginBtn.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
   username = loginInput.value;
   if (username.length > 0) {
     send({ type: "login", name: username });
   }
 });

 // Setup a peer connection with another user 
 connectToOtherUsernameBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {

   let otherUsername = otherUsernameInput.value;
   connectedUser = otherUsername;
   if (otherUsername.length <= 0) return;
   // Make an offer 
   myConnection.createOffer((offer) => {
     console.log("Offer");
     send({ type: "offer", offer: offer });
     myConnection.setLocalDescription(offer);
   }, (error) => {
     alert("An error has occurred.");
   });
 });

 // When a user clicks the send message button 
 sendMsgBtn.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
   var val = msgInput.value;
   console.log(`Send message: ${val}`);
   dataChannel.send(val);
 });

 // Handle messages from the server 
 connection.onmessage = (message) => {
   console.log("Got message: ", message.data);
   let data = JSON.parse(message.data);

   switch (data.type) {
     case "login":
       onLogin(data.success);
       break;
     case "offer":
       onOffer(data.offer, data.name);
       break;
     case "answer":
       onAnswer(data.answer);
       break;
     case "candidate":
       onCandidate(data.candidate);
       break;
     default:
       break;
   }
 };

 // When a user logs in 
 function onLogin(success) {
   if (success === false) {
     alert("Oops... Try a different username");
     return;
   }
   // Creating our RTCPeerConnection object 
   var configuration = {
     "iceServers": [
       { "urls": "stun:stun.1.google.com:19302" }
     ]
   };

   myConnection = new RTCPeerConnection(configuration);
   console.log("RTCPeerConnection object was created");
   console.log(myConnection);

   // Setup ice handling
   // When the browser finds an ice candidate we send it to another peer 
   myConnection.onicecandidate = (event) => {
     if (event.candidate) {
       send({ type: "candidate", candidate: event.candidate });
     }
   };
   openDataChannel();
 };

 //when somebody wants to call us 
 function onOffer(offer, name) {
   connectedUser = name;
   myConnection.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(offer));

   myConnection.createAnswer((answer) => {
     myConnection.setLocalDescription(answer);
     send({ type: "answer", answer: answer });
   }, (error) => {
     alert("Oops... Error");
   });
}

 // When another user answers to our offer 
 function onAnswer(answer) {
   myConnection.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(answer));
 }

 // When we got ice candidate from another user 
 function onCandidate(candidate) {
   myConnection.addIceCandidate(new RTCIceCandidate(candidate));
 }



 connection.onopen = function () {
   console.log("Connected");
 };

 connection.onerror = function (err) {
   console.log("Got error", err);
 };

 // Alias for sending messages in JSON format 
 function send(message) {
   if (connectedUser) message.name = connectedUser;
   connection.send(JSON.stringify(message));
 };

 // Creating data channel 
 function openDataChannel() {
   dataChannel = myConnection.createDataChannel("myDataChannel");
   console.log(dataChannel);

   dataChannel.onerror = (error) => {
     console.log("Error:", error);
   };

   dataChannel.onmessage = (event) => {
     console.log("Got message: ", event.data);
   };
 }
```

I tried to debug the connection using `chrome://webrtc-internals/` and everything seems to work fine but when I the RTCDataChannel of the receiver has no messagesReceived.

Comment: The code you've pasted as a js client is the same as the code for signalling server :)

Comment: @Ivan sorry for the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine, but you missing datachannel/message callback.

Add this code after `RTCPeerConnection` initialization and you should see messages in the console.

```js
myConnection.ondatachannel = ((dc) => {
    const channel = dc.channel;
    console.log('Got data channel', channel);
    channel.onmessage = ((message) => {
        console.log('Got message', message.data);
    })
})
```

You can find an example [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API/Simple_RTCDataChannel_sample).

Btw, data channels in webrtc are bidirectional, so you might create a single one on a caller side and then use it on a callee side as well (you will get the object for communication in `ondatachannel` callback).